# GAMS: Is there a way to retrieve the gap from the final solve statement

Tags: cplex, gams, test-instances

Good evening,
I am looking for a way to retrieve information from the final solve statement. Lower bound and Gap would be nice. I am working with the python api but i can only get the final obj. value and all parameters etc..
Is there a way to store the information I need in a parameter and what would be the command?

I want to access and store the underlined values in the picture..

[image]

Comment: Would you see `.lst` file in the GAMS directory?

Comment: yes i see the solution report in the .lst there but i need to automate the whole thing

Comment: What you mean by automating the whole thing? When the problem is solved this file is generated automatically with the full reports.

Comment: I am solving multiple problems in a loop.. it's a bit tedious to get the data I want from the report

Comment: UPDATE: my current workaround:
use put Model.objest (this is what i found out how to get the lower bound)
into a temporary.txt and access that via python
kinda cumbersome but at least it works

Answer (score 5):

Collecting things in a parameter is actually very simple.

```
set run /.../;

parameter objresult(run,*);

loop(run,  
    solve m ....
    objresult(run,"obj") = m.objval;
    objresult(run,"bestbound") = m.objest;
    objresult(run,"absgap") = abs(m.objval-m.objest);
);
```

Comment: will this parameter be in the .lst file?

Comment: Otherwise i can't access it via the python api i think. Parameters which arent part of the actual model arent in the .lst?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you are saying here. The listing file is well just a listing file. I fail to see the connection with the Python API. This makes no sense.